# Where does Windows 10 store file association?

Tags: windows-10, pdf, file-association

When I create a new local user on Windows 10, the .pdf file associations are inconsistend. According to `ftype` .pdf files (`AcroExch.Document.11`) are associated with AcroRd32.exe. 
But if the user doubleclicks on a .pdf file, Windows opens it with Edge. Its possible to change the default program on the Windows GUI via properties-open with..., but I need to find a way to do it by commandline. Setting the file associations via GPO as [suggested by adobe](https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/pdfviewer.html) rules out, since the computer is not member of a domain. I tried `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.pdf` but this is ignored too.

Comment: The registry same as previous versions

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command 'assoc' (you will need to run the command in Command Prompt as Administrator to change the association). Despite being an old command it still exists in Windows 10. The details: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490865.aspx